# Can I dynamically filter an array of names with Angular with a user input character?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, filtering

I am presently playing around with some Angular examples that I found over here - https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/guide/filter

I am using the built in filterFilter filter (he he) and I have read that I may need to create my own filter (so I can pass params) however seems like I should not have to if the filter will just re-run. The idea I am working on is to try to let the user define the character that is used to filter the array.

My present code looks like so:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('FilterInControllerModule', [])
  .controller('FilterController', ['filterFilter', function(filterFilter) {
    this.filterChar = 'a';
    this.array = [
      {name: 'Tobias'},
      {name: 'John'},
      {name: 'Jack'},
      {name: 'Frank'},
      {name: 'Desmond'},
      {name: 'Allan'},
      {name: 'Margie'}
    ];
    this.filteredArray = filterFilter(this.array, this.filterChar);
  }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Filters Extended Example 1</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="FilterInControllerModule">
    <div ng-controller="FilterController as ctrl">
      Filter by character: <input ng-model="ctrl.filterChar" type="text" maxlength="1"><br><br>
      <div>
        All entries:
        <div ng-repeat="entry in ctrl.array">{{entry.name}}</div>
      </div><br>
      <div>
        Entries that contain an "{{ctrl.filterChar}}":
        <div ng-repeat="entry in ctrl.filteredArray">{{entry.name}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you run the code you will find that the two-way binding between the model and view is working between the controller and the expression {{ctrl.filterChar}} however the controller does not seem to re-evaluate the actual filtering. Why might this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because your function filterFilter is only evaluated once. To re-evaluate it and get the filtered array on every digest cycle, you can do this:

In your controller, use a function:

```
var that = this;
this.filterMyArray = function() {
    return filterFilter(that.array, that.filterChar);
}
```

...and in your html

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in ctrl.filterMyArray()">{{entry.name}}</div>
```

Comment: Most excellent! Thank you - I will update the code above to reflect these changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in your controller:

```
  var myApp = angular.module('FilterInControllerModule', [])
   .controller('FilterController', ['filterFilter', function(filterFilter) {
      this.filterChar = 'a';
      this.array = [
        {name: 'Tobias'},
        {name: 'John'},
        {name: 'Jack'},
        {name: 'Frank'},
        {name: 'Desmond'},
        {name: 'Allan'},
        {name: 'Margie'}
      ];
      this.filterFilter = function() {
         return this.array.filter(function(element, index, sourceArray) {
              return element.name.indexOf(this.filterChar) !== -1;
         }.bind(this));
      }
   }]);
```

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't do it either. The result is the same, no changes to the filtered set.